# Where is Host-only Networks setting on VirtualBox 4.3.12?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

- I'm using `VirtualBox 4.3.12 r93733` (with Ubuntu as guest OS, and Windows 7 as host OS).
- Trying to configure a *Host-only Network*, I expected to see the following window (or similar):

[image: Host-only Network configuration window]

- However, under `Settings/Network,` all I see are *NIC* configuration options:

[image: Settings/Network]

### Where do I configure Host-only Networks on VirtualBox 4.3.12?

Answer (score 0):

Found it on `File/Preferences/Network.`